# PHP, REGEXP как найти закрывающую скобку выражения в тексте

Tags: php, строки

Есть текст с выражениями, вида
`\run{{A} {B}} {{{C}}{D}}{E}`
Как я могу гарантировано получить часть `\run{{A}` ? Нужно поставить разделитель между {A} и {B}, при условии что содержимое A может содержать вложенные выражения в скобках  `A = {{test}{test}}` По сути нужно найти Закрывающую скобку конкретного выражения. Я пробовал `/\\run{(.*)}/` и затем `/{([\s\S]+?)}/` но это работает только если не появляется дополнительной вложенности выражений

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем случае математические и текстовые выражения со сложной скобочной структурой не парсятся регулярками. Так или иначе, без перебора не обойтись.

Если у вас А - это строго то, что находится после  `\run{{` и перед }, которая относится к этой второй скобке:  \run{`{`, то так:

- заводите счетчик `i = 0;`
- также инициализируете `resStr = '\run{{';`
- начинаете перебор с символа сразу после `\run{{`
- если символ == "{", то i++, если == "}", то i--, если символ не скобка - ничего
- на каждом шагу добавляете проверяемый символ в `resStr`
- просматриваете строку до тех пор пока счетчик `i не станет == -1`
- все. `resStr == '\run{{...}'`

Ну и замена `\run{{...}` на `\run{{...}delimiter`